# PackagesNotFoundError for r-ikernel

Tags: r, jupyter

I'm relatively new to R and python, and I want to run the newest version of R on jupyter notebook. I did the following commands:

- conda create -n r-kernel
- conda activate r-kernel
- When I run conda install -c -r rikernel, I am getting a Packagesnotfounderror. Here is a screenshot: [image]

I tried doing conda config --append channels conda-forge but this also didn't fix my issue. Is there something I can do to fix this?

Comment: You have a typo, see `r-irkernel` used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61508508/8508004). In screenshot (**HIGHLY FROWNED ON IN A POSTS ON THIS SITE**) you have `r-ikernel`. Also in text you say,"When I run conda install -c -r rikernel, I am getting a Packagesnotfounderror."  Please copy and paste commands from established guides. Additionally your install command  you are trying to run inside a running notebook, should start `%conda install  ...`. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the ...

Comment: <continued> modern magic install commands added in 2019 to insure that install commands run inside an active Jupyter notebook with a Python based kernel install the packages to the environment where the kernel is running. These are current best practice now (you can use that to help discern outdated information you find) and work universally in modern Jupyter, such as even in JupyterLite and Google Colab now.